# Want to return a string from PHP to AJAX on success using laravel (or regular PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

How do I return a string from a PHP document, and then do something if(string == 'test')
Should I assign dataType? Should I use return or echo?
Here's what I currently have.

AJAX CODE:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'phonegap',
                data: senddata,
                success: function(response) {
                    var a = $(this).html(response);

                    if(a == 'Success')
                        alert("YAY");
                    else
                        alert("NAY");
                },
```

PHP CODE / LARAVEL

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                //return $user->utid;
                return "Success";
            }
            else {
                return "Error";
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your ajax call add this option:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

In php, you can put all data you need into an array and then simply print out json of that array with:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

When you do that, response object in javascript will containt all your array data.

For example, if you define array like `$results = array('success' => true);`, in javascript you can check whether response.success is true or false. You can pass multiple values this way.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'phonegap',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: senddata,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success)
            alert("YAY");
        else
            alert("NAY");
    }
});
```

And in PHP

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $result = array('success' => false, 'userid' => $user->utid);
}
else {
    $result = array('success' => false);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Using this, I got parseError. I also got parseError earlier using laravels response::json

success: function(response) {
     if(response.success == true)
      alert("YAY");
     else
      alert("NAY");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with echo ? I'm sure it must work

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
  $user = Auth::user();
  // return $user->utid;
  echo "Success";
  exit;
} else {
  echo "Error";
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of key things:

-`$(this)` within your `success` callback doesn't refer to the original element

-Use `echo` to return a response

You can set a context variable to the current element via:

```
var that = $(this)

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) {
        var a = that.html(response);

        if(a == 'Success')
            alert("YAY");
        else
            alert("NAY");
    },
});
```

And simply `echo` your response back from the server.

Comment: Then your response isn't getting returned. Check the console and make sure the request isn't errorinhg